# Optimizer from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

I would like to translate following problem from Matlab to Python (Matlab Code):

```
  function [f,g] = rosenbrockwithgrad(x)
    f = 100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1-x(1))^2;

    if nargout > 1 % gradient required
      g = [-400*(x(2)-x(1)^2)*x(1)-2*(1-x(1));
      200*(x(2)-x(1)^2)];
   end
```

Then call the optimiser:

```
   options = optimoptions('fminunc','Algorithm','trust-region','SpecifyObjectiveGradient',true);
   fminunc(@(x) rosenbrockwithgrad(x),x0,options)
```

Python:

```
  def rosenbrockwithgrad(x, nargout = 1):
    f = 100*(x[1] - x[0]**2)**2 + (1-x([0]))**2;

    if nargout > 1: #gradient
     g = ([-400*(x[1]-x[0]**2)*x[0]-2*(1-x[0]), 200*(x[1]-x[0])**2]);
   return f,g
```

Then call the optimiser:

```
   scipy.optimise.fmin_cg(...no idea...)
```

Is it necessary to split up the function or is there a similar way like in Matlab?

Comment: you could use the `scipy.optimize` function inside your `rosenbrockwithgrad` definition.  As a side note, is there any reason you have an extra pair of `()` on the outside when you assign a value to `g`? Also, in python we don't use `;` to end lines.